# Limit number quantity in emailed Google Sheets chart

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

I have a statistical chart which will be sent to my email address on a daily basis. However, it is getting messy because daily data is growing in the graph:

[image]

I don't want too many numbers being shown on the chart, but some numbers indication is desired.

How to do that?

The chart is built as follows:

```js
  var formChart = RawDatass.newChart()
              .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
              .addRange(RawDatass.getRange(range))
              .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0)
              //.setOption('title', 'The Key Sathorn-Charoenraj Sales & Rental Trend')
              .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', 35)
              .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', 100)
              .setOption('series', series)
              .setOption('legend', 'right')
             // .setOption('theme', 'maximized')
              .build();
```

Comment: you could set a `viewWindow` on the `hAxis` -- not sure what you mean by _some numbers indication is desired_

Comment: Where is your definition of `series`? That's what controls the formatted representation of your chart data...

Comment: In general terms, what you need to do is define some way to compute your series' desired *data labels*. If you don't want to have a label for a given data point, its label would be `""`. For your "Sales - HF" series, comparing the previous and following data points for equality, and if true, omitting the data point, works well: `=if(and(b2=b1,b2=b3), "", b2)` https://i.imgur.com/aMoOi0C.png (sales-hf is in column B, with labels as own range in col e)